# Convert for hooks

Tags: react-native, hook, i18next

I'm still getting the react native hooks and I would like some help converting a const.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Booking extends React.Component {
    
    myTitle = () => {
        const { people } = this.props;

        const nameFirst = idx(people, __ => __.nameFirst);

        return nameFirst ? i18n.t('Generate.NameOk', {nameFirst}) : i18n.t('Generate.NameNull');
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                {this.myTitle()}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

The way I did it is correct?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'i18next';

function Booking() {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    
    const myTitle = () => {
        const [ people, setPeople ] = useState();

        const nameFirst = idx(people, __ => __.nameFirst);

        return nameFirst ? t('Generate.NameOk', {nameFirst}) : t('Generate.NameNull');
    };

    return(
        <View>
            {myTitle()}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: why use function instead of const Booking = () => ... ?

Comment: i think hooks should be use only in components , here booking will be a component since it returns some jsx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be correct:

```
export const Booking = () =>  { 
const { t } = useTranslation();
const [ people, setPeople ] = useState();

const myTitle = () => {
    const nameFirst = idx(people, __ => __.nameFirst);
    return nameFirst ? t('Generate.NameOk', {nameFirst}) : t('Generate.NameNull');
};

 return(
    <View>
        {myTitle()}
    </View>
 )
}
```